# Using oAuth with Asp.net and Zapier

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I am wondering if anyone has setup an Asp.net App to use oAuth 2 and Zapier. Does anyone have an example to setup asp.net web api 2 app to authenticate from the OWIN providers so that Zapier can authenticate users?

I am not looking for an example to login into a 3rd party app like FB, Google, ect to my app. But I am looking to expose my application as an oAuth provider so Zapier can authenticate my users from my system.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Zapier, but the principles of setting up claims based authentication using OWIN and hosting your own authentication server should be the same.

[This article](http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/) provides a good description of decoupling the authentication and resources.

[A second article](http://blog.mszcool.com/index.php/2013/12/asp-net-4-5-1-webapi-general-integration-with-oauth2-and-oauth-authentication-servers/) show another example of how to do this.